# Does the expression "daba por curada" exist and what does it mean?

Tags: verbos, expresiones

I was listening to *Deja Vu* by Shakira / Prince Royce.

The opening line has this phrase:

> Tú me abriste las heridas que daba por curada con tequila...

Is "daba por curada" actually a phrase? I was expecting something like "había curado" instead, but a search on the internet only returns the "daba por curada" result.

Comment: To be grammatical, it should be "daba por curada**s**", as "curadas" refers to "heridas" (plural).

Comment: And possibly a comma missing, too.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it exists.

> Dar por + *participle* = take as + *participle*

It basically means that "dar por curadas" means "take as healed", as in "presume the wounds are healed". It's like if you're the tester and you approve that their state is such that they can be treated as helaed".

In the same way,

dar por hecho = dar por supuesto = take for granted

By the way, in your example, you're talking about "las heridas" (the wounds), so it would be "daba por curadas las heridas".

Comment: Most phrases I this same structure convey the idea of taking something for granted.

Comment: Agree with answer and comment.  So what it means in the lyric is *You reopened the wounds I thought had been healed with tequila* which suggests that the singer was using "healed" a bit sarcastically.

Comment: don't forget to change the verb to past or add a "did" to change it to the past tense : "the wounds which i did take for healed with/by tequila"